# A specific consequence of Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

If *f* is holomorphic in an open subset $G \subset \mathbb{C}$, and if $f'(a)\neq0$ for some $a \in G$, then there exists $r>0$ such that \begin{eqnarray}|f'(z)-f'(a)|<|f'(a)|,\end{eqnarray} for $z \in D(a,r)$ ($D$ for 'disk' with centre $a$, radius $r$).

The above is what I intend to prove.
I've tried to use Cauchy's integral formulae, i.e \begin{eqnarray}2\pi i f'(z)=\int_{\partial D(a,r)}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2} \, dw,\end{eqnarray} or \begin{eqnarray}2\pi i f'(z)=\int_{\partial D(a,r)}\frac{f'(w)}{w-z} \, dw,\end{eqnarray}

but I don't get anywhere? If someone would give a hint I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see a question. Perhaps you intended to ask how to prove the statement in the first sentence?

Comment: Yes of course. My bad :)

Comment: Probably you can differentiate the power series for $f$ centered at $a$ and estimate the remainder when $z$ is very close to $a$.

Comment: I will try to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Cauchy's integral formula for this. A holomorphic function is infinitely differentiable, so its derivative is continuous. Your inequality is an instance of the $\delta$-$\epsilon$-definition of the continuity of $f'$, with $\delta=r$ and $\epsilon=|f'(a)|\gt0$.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I was so excited to have learned CIF that I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate
$$
f(z)=f(a)+f'(a)(z-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2} (z-a)^2 + \ldots
$$
and deduce
$$
f'(z)=f'(a)+f''(a)(z-a)+\ldots
$$
Since the power series $f''(a)(z-a)+\ldots$ vanishes at $a$ and $f'(a) \neq 0$, there exists a radius $r>0$ such that $|f''(a)(z-a)+\ldots| < |f'(a)|$ whenever $|z-a|<r$.

Answer (score 1):

$f'$ is continous as $f$ is holomorphic. So we can apply the definition of continuity with $\varepsilon:=\frac{|f'(a)|}2$.